# How to always print 2 digits after the decimal separator?

Tags: javascript

The program im trying to create should separate numbers to 3 categories.

1 - average: 2 - below average: 3 - above average:

For example

1. (input - 3,-12,0,0,13,5,1,0,-2) = (output - avg: 0.89 below: -12,0,0,0,-2 above: 3,13,5,1)
2. (input - 0,1,-1) = (output - avg: 0.00 below: -1 above: 1).

My code does the first example, but is unable to do the second one. It gives me just 0 on the average value.
The average should always have two digits after the decimal separator.

I cannot find a way to add those 2 digits zeroes after the decimal point for the average value.

```js
let input = ['0', '1', '-1'];
let gets = this.gets || ((arr, index) => () => arr[index++])(input, 0);

var numberArray = [];
length = input.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  numberArray.push(parseInt(input[i]));

var sum = 0;
for (var number of numberArray) {
  sum += number;
}
average = sum / numberArray.length;
var result = [];

let allNums = numberArray.filter(v => v > numberArray.reduce((x, y) => x + y) / numberArray.length);
let below = numberArray.filter(v => v > numberArray.reduce((y, x) => y + x) / numberArray.length);

for (let i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
  if (numberArray[i] < average) {
    result.push(numberArray[i]);
  }
}

const result3 = parseFloat(average)
  .toFixed(2);
console.log("avg:", +result3);
console.log(`below: ${result}`.toString());
console.log(`above: ${allNums}`.toString());
```

Comment: @ruleboy21 Maybe the lack of [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) before asking?

Comment: `let a = 23.12345;
let b = Number.parseFloat(a).toFixed(2);
console.log(b);`
hope this was helpful
please refer @mplungjan comment to understand how this work

Comment: why not take numbers directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to easily handle this instead of using multiple loops. Try this

```js
function beforeOrAfterAvg(input){
    let average = input.reduce((sum, val) => sum + parseFloat(val), 0) / (input.length || 1);
    let below   = input.filter(val => parseFloat(val) < average);
    let above   = input.filter(val => parseFloat(val) > average);

    return {
        average: average.toFixed(2),
        below: below,
        above: above
    }
}

let input = ['0','1','-1'];
let result = beforeOrAfterAvg(input);

// console.log(result);

console.log("avg:", result.average);
console.log("below:", result.below.join(', '));
console.log("above:", result.above.join(', '));
```